# Xcode: layout good on 4S, 5/6 not

Tags: iphone, autolayout, constraints, xcode7

i have a simple label and a webview on my view controller. On 4s and 5 the width is perfect, but on 6, there is a "white band" on the right.. What do you need to configure in constraints, to let "grow" the webview in length on 5, and in width & length on 6/6+? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autolayout classes are tricky part:

1. create all your components on w-Any, h-Any so they **would appear on all iOS devices**.
2. start creating constrains that targets certain device by

   1. changing w-any, h-any to the one that you like.
   2. reposition your label, and web view
   3. bottom,left of your interface builder define new constrains for the label and web view based on margins.
3. you can add more labels/UI elements that would only appear on that class of devices (iPhone 6/6+)

You can check the layout without running the simulator:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/Chapters/PreviewingLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009971-CH5